# Xcode 5.0.1 iOS 7.0.3 Simulator Not launching

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I just upgraded to Xcode 5.0.1 on OSX Mavericks and upgraded Xcode to 5.0.1.  When I try to launch an app on iOS 7.0.3 Simulator, the Simulator won't launch.  The app will launch on iOS 6.1 Simulator, but the iOS 7.0.3 Simulator just gets stuck on a black screen.

Anyone else have this issue?  I've tried re-installing XCode as well and still get the same problem.

Comment: FYI This is happening for all my iOS apps.  The iOS 7 simulator just shows a black screen.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one!  https://devforums.apple.com/message/910435#910435

Comment: UPDATE: I waited 15 min and eventually it showed up according https://devforums.apple.com/message/910435#910435.  Then I installed the updated docs as well and now it launches fine every time.  Wierd.

Comment: Looks like the first time you launch iOS 7.0.3 simulator in an Xcode session, it takes 15 min to launch.  Then subsequent launches come up right away.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. It scared a hell out of me...

Comment: @UzairKhan are you sure it lunches fast after first time taking 15min? because in my case I have to wait everytime :(

Answer (score 8):

I'm also having same problem in Xcode 5.0.1/OS X 10.8.5. Finally, able to resolve it.

First clean project (Cmd+K) and then run your project the iOS 6.1 simulator. When app is running well in iOS 6.1, stop the app (Cmd+dot)  in Xcode and switch to Simulator app and reset it. Then change it iOS 7.0.3 (from hardware menu) and again reset it after 2-3 min. Now you should see the iOS 7 simulator working. Doh...

Comment: Thanks! This was the only way I got it working again.

Answer (score 7):

This is what works for me:

1. Quit the simulator
2. Start the simulator manually from Xcode (Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> iOS Simulator) and wait for it to load completely
3. Run the app

Answer (score 0):

Quit the simulator and run again it worked for me.

Comment: I've tried this and the iOS 7 simulator just shows a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

- Switch to iOS 7 in simulator using `Hardware` menu.
- Then launch your project from XCode and hit `Project->Run` using any scheme which is not iOS 7. This will build it for iOS 7.
- If it does not launch in iOS 7, hit Home, and repeat from step 1.

Comment: I've tried this and the iOS 7 simulator just shows a black screen.

Comment: In which case it is not iOS 7 specific issue. Try restarting simulator as @himan says.

Comment: I've tried restarting the simulator many times and even re-installed Xcode

Comment: Try killing your app: Long press home button on simulator - it will show running apps. Press '-' sign upon your app to kill it. There are other Terminal solutions to kill an iOS app. Search online.

Comment: It won't even launch the simulator...I can't even use iOS on the simulator...it just shows a black screen.  Command-Shift-H does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your simulator clean and build again it worked for me it might work for you as well

Answer (score 0):

Apple just released Xcode 5.0.2 GM Seed to developers which resolves this issue as per release notes: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_5.0.2_gm_seed/xcode_5.0.2_gm_seed_release_notes.pdf