# IOS 7 simulator doesn't work at all

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode5

I've got annoying problem with IOS Simulator at Xcode 5. It doesn't work at all.
I've been searching for a week around different forums and there are a lot of variants of solving this problem. But nothing could help me. I reseted the simulators content and settings, deleted some files connected to simulator, reinstalled Xcode, but everything is hopeless.
My Simulator shows black screen and debuger says:

iPhone Simulator[573] : Could not lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.host_support: 3

iPhone Simulator[573] : Unable to update keyboard layout because we were unable to connect to the host_support mach service.

iPhone Simulator[573] : Could not lookup service com.apple.iphonesimulator.bridge: 3

iPhone Simulator[573] : Error communicating with SimulatorBridge: NSObjectNotAvailableException - Unable to connect to SimulatorBridge

There is absolutely the same problem here, but there is no proper answer:
[xcode5 iOS Simulator failed to install the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914786/xcode5-ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running Xcode version 5.0.2? From the linked answer: "This is a known bug in Xcode 5.0.1. The updated version 5.0.2 addresses this issue."

Comment: Yes Xcode version 5.0.2

Comment: This answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570622/608448

Comment: Andrea Sprega thank you too much, but no (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do, it may not help.

1. Run TimeMachine, you really **need an up-to-date backup**. Make sure
   it ran successfully.
2. Make sure you are running 10.9.2.
3. Delete Xcode by dragging it from the Applications folder to the trash
4. Delete ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator Empty the
   trash.
5. Delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode (this has some user profile things
   in it, the TM backup will have a copy if needed later)
6. Make sure there is no other Xcode or Simulator on the computer,
   Spotlight is a good place to start. Delete anything found and empty
   the trash.
7. Empty the trash.
8. Reboot
9. Install Xcode 5.0.2 from the AppStore.

Comment: Thanks! This works. The issue that I encountered is when I accidentally altered the permission of the applications, not knowing that it's bad for some programs. Thanks for your solution!